# get 404 Not Found error on swagger loading documentation when using using nginx server but working fine locally

Tags: nestjs, swagger, http-status-code-404, documentation, swagger-ui

here is my code of main.ts::

```
declare const module: any
async function bootstrap() {
    try {
        const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
            .setTitle('Next Supply Chain Management')
            .setDescription('The NSCM Swagger APIs ')
            .setVersion('3.0')
            .addTag('NSCM')
            .addBearerAuth()
            .build()
        const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig)
        SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document)
```

here is my nginx configuration file

```
nscm@fnbdev:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ cat fnbdev.vteamslabs.com
server {
        server_name fnbdev.vteamslabs.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/fnbdev.vteamslabs.com-access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/fnbdev.vteamslabs.com-error.log error;

        root /home/nscm/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Upload Max File Size
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        # Frontend
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }

        # Backend
        location /api/ {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.socket;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name                                                                                                                     ;
        }

        # Prevents caching of css/less/js/images, only use this in development
        location ~* \.(css|less|js)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                expires 0;
                try_files $uri =404;  # Add this line to handle the file request                                                                                                                     s
        }
 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fnbdev.vteamslabs.com/fullchain.pem; #                                                                                                                      managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fnbdev.vteamslabs.com/privkey.pem;                                                                                                                      # managed by Certbot
#    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
 #   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

}
```

Everything is working fine locally but not for the staging server the code is same.

Swagger documentation loading locally
[Local server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcM9X.png)

But on my dev server it is not showing

[Dev server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF3B1.png)

I have to do some modifications in configuration file?
Anyone can provide the authentic working solution of this??